# Adding new field to an existing Web Service custom type

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx, custom-type

I have a web service GetPieByName which returns a custom type Pie:

```
public Pie GetPieByName(string name)
{
Pie p = new Pie();
p.name = "Apple Pie";
return p;
}

class Pie {    
string name    
get set methods... 
}
```

Pie p definition only has name in it. Caller A uses the web service.

Down the road after a few months, Pie p definition is enhanced to include weight, expiry date. This will be used by Caller B. Upon deployment of the enhanced web service, do I need to do anything to Caller A? Will it still work if I don't refresh the service reference wsdl?

Comment: What kind of service? ASMX?

Comment: Yes, its a. asmx webservice

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Correction. The service is a .svc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caller A would still works as usual, despite the additional properties in the type.

However, until the WSDL is refreshed, the additional properties of the `Pie` is invisible to caller A.

Answer (score -2):

create another PIE method that will handle **CALLER B**
then do if statement on your GetPieByName()
check if its **CALLER A** or **CALLER B**

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question. Besides, that would be a duplication of codes.